# Is LEAD a reserved word in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

For this simple table, created in MySQL 8.012

```
CREATE TABLE `lead` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TS` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `RS` json DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

The statement

```
INSERT INTO lead (ID,RS) VALUES (1397,'{"ID":"1397","TITLE":"John Lenon -TESTE ZAPIER 54","HONORIFIC":"0"}') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE RS = VALUES(RS);
```

FAILS when submitted through PhpMysqladmin with error

Static analysis:

3 errors were found during analysis.

> Unrecognized keyword. (near "ON" at position 111) Unrecognized
>   keyword. (near "DUPLICATE" at position 114) Unrecognized keyword.
>   (near "KEY" at position 124)

SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO lead (ID,RS) VALUES 
  (1397,'{"ID":"1397","TITLE":"John Lenon -TESTE ZAPIER 54","HONORIFIC":"0"}') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE RS = VALUES(RS)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'lead (ID,RS) VALUES (1397,'{"ID":"1397","TITLE":"John Lenon
>   -TESTE ZAPIER 54","H' at line 1

However, if the table name is changed, say, to "myleader", the statement works like a charm.

Any thoughts?
Thanks
Ronaldo

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `LEAD` is a reserved word:

> LEAD (R); added in 8.0.2 (reserved)

[MySQL Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

Comment: Once again the documentation saves the day!

Comment: But perhaps worth noting that this does *not* mean you can't have a table called `lead`. You just have to be more explicit about the name: `\`lead\``

Comment: tried to be explicit but wouldn't work. Using LIDA instead.